# Java issues with updating variables correctly

Tags: java

I have the following `Account` class which is the super class of `CurrentAccount`. I am however having issues when I create an instance of each class. The `currentAccount` should take away 6 as a charge if the balance is below 100 but its taking away 3. I'm obviously missing a deceleration somewhere.

```
public class Account {

    private String name;
    private double balance;
    public double initDeposit;
    public double threshold = 100.00;
    public final double fee = 3.00;

    public Account(String name, double initDeposit) {
        this.balance = initDeposit;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        setBalance(amount);
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        if (getBalance() < 100 && getBalance() >= -50) {
            balance = balance - amount - fee;
        } else {
            balance = balance - amount;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Balance: " + balance;
        return s;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CurrentAccount extends Account {

    private String name;
    private double balance;
    public double initDeposit;
    public double threshold = 100.00;
    public final double fee = 6.00;

    public CurrentAccount(String name, double initDeposit) {
        super(name, initDeposit);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `"taking away 6"` and `"taking away 3"`?

Comment: Your seem to be trying to _overide_ instance variables but are in fact **shadowing** them. You need to pass variables you want into the superclass constructor rather than redeclare them.

Comment: What happens if the balance is less than -50 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, instance variables do not replace or override the same named variable in a superclass.  If you declare a same-named variable in a subclass, now you have two variables, not one.  Just because you declared another `fee` in `CurrentAccount` doesn't mean the code in `Account` will use the `fee` in `CurrentAccount` -- it can't.

To apply the different behavior you need, declare a method called `getFee()` in `Account` returning a `double` that can be overridden in `CurrentAccount` to change the behavior.

In Account:

```
public double getFee() { return 3.00; }
```

In CurrentAccount:

```
@Override
public double getFee() { return 6.00; }
```

Then call `getFee()` whenever you need to reference the fee, instead of referring to `fee`.